# Powershell Bulk creation of volume access paths from csv

Tags: powershell, csv, variables, bulk

Help please if you have done this before. I have a script that works when I type the values in but when extracting the values from csv it gives an error as value not recognized.

I have tried different ways of concatenating the values extracted from .csv (for example using the join-path) but still seems that add-partitionaccesspath was not made to accept values from csv. surely this cannot be correct? The following code created the drives and creates the folders to be mounted and partitions, formats and labels all the drives. However the folders are not created as mountpoints

```
$localmachine = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$csv = '\\sharedpath\disks.csv' 
foreach ($Row in (import-csv $csv | Where-Object {$_.server -eq $localmachine} )){
        $Letter = $row.Letter
        $disk1 = $Row.disk1
        $disk2 = $Row.disk2
        $disk3 = $row.disk3
        $disk4 = $row.disk4

    $label1 = $row.label1
    $label2 = $row.label2
    $label3 = $row.label3
    $label4 = $row.label4

New-Partition –DiskNumber $disk1 -DriveLetter $Letter -UseMaximumSize
Format-Volume -DriveLetter $Letter -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel $label1 –allocationUnitSize 65536 -Confirm:$false

New-Partition –DiskNumber $disk2 -UseMaximumSize
$part2 = Get-Partition -DiskNumber $disk2 
$accessP2 = join-path $Letter -ChildPath $label2
New-Item –itemType Directory –path $accessP2
$Part2 | Format-Volume –FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel $label2 –allocationUnitSize 65536 –Confirm:$false
$Part2 | Add-PartitionAccessPath –AccessPath $accessP2

New-Partition –DiskNumber $disk3 -UseMaximumSize
$part3 = Get-Partition -DiskNumber $disk3 
$accessP3 = join-path $Letter -ChildPath $label3
New-Item –itemType Directory –path $accessP3
$Part3 | Format-Volume –FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel $label3 –allocationUnitSize 65536 –Confirm:$false
$Part3 | Add-PartitionAccessPath –AccessPath $accessP3

New-Partition –DiskNumber $disk4 -UseMaximumSize
$part4 = Get-Partition -DiskNumber $disk4 
$accessP4 = join-path $Letter -ChildPath $label4
New-Item –itemType Directory –path $accessP4
$Part4 | Format-Volume –FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel $label4 –allocationUnitSize 65536 –Confirm:$false
$Part4 | Add-PartitionAccessPath –AccessPath $accessP4

}
```

the expected results are that it should assign the $accessP* value to the Add-PartitinAccessPath -AccessPath in the format of e:\foldername (as enumerated in the csv file below) however even though $accessp* always returns the correct string value like e:\staging_log01 it gives an error when the script runs the last line of each iteration

```
$Part# | Add-PartitionAccessPath –AccessPath $accessP#
```

but if I put in

```
$Part4 | Add-PartitionAccessPath –AccessPath staging_log01
```

it works!!!
How comes this is?

csv file is formatted like so?
Letter  server  disk1   label1  disk2   Label2     disk3    Label3
E:  server1     1      mount    2   STAGING_Log01   3     STAGING_System01 
E:  server2    1      mount    2    AGING_Log01     3   STAGING_Log01

Comment: Does the Label4 header exist in the CSV? It is not there in your example.

Comment: yes it does, the error is against every iteration anyway. I had problems pasting the csv contents as good as I wished to it actually goes up to label9, disk9 etc, so I had to make it smaller it for the purpose of the question sorry. But I can confirm the issue is not with the csv contents.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that I just ran it line by line without getting the variable values from a network shared csv file
and it worked. But for some reason if I do it in bulk it fails???!!! I hope its not something silly like needing to rescan and let it have time to refresh between executing the last 2 lines

Comment: Whenever I have used these commands in the past, I always turn off the shell hardware detection service to prevent interactive actions from happening while disk provisioning. I just run `stop-service shellHWDetection` at the beginning of the script. Then run `start-service shellHWDetection` when I'm done with disk provisioning.

Comment: I'll take that on-board thanks and I've tried it, My script still fails still when it uses variables taken from .csv. for example $accessp2 = join-path $Letter -ChildPath $label2 gives me the value E:\STAGING_Log01 for variable $accessp2, after taken from csv. $accessp2.getType().Fullname also confirms that it is a "system.string" value. But what is strange is I get the error "Add-PartitionAccessPath : Invalid Parameter after it has taken the exact same value from .csv no matter how I get it.

Comment: But bizarrely if I just input $accessp2 = "E:\STAGING_Log01" and then call "New-Item –itemType Directory –path $accessP2 " followed by "New-Item –itemType Directory –path $accessP2" and finally "New-Item –itemType Directory –path $accessP2" it works exactly as expected.... its as if Powershell is not too reliable with getting values .csv files or I'm missing something ?? In both occassions the $accessP2 variable shows to be a system string as it should be so it cannot be a problem with the type. Any ideas any one please?

Comment: Is the file actually full of comma-separated values or tab-separated values?

Comment: its input from excel and saved as csv. It detects the name column ok as well as the label column, because after getting the errors when I type the $variable name, it outputs the correct string for example E:\staging_log01 so I cannot understand if it has the correct string why does it not accept?

Comment: Is it possible that there are some whitespace characters after the name? Can you try `$accessP4.Trim()` in your command?

Comment: That is a very good guess, and happened to be exactly what  the problem was. I thank you very much!!!